# Inexpensive enterprise chat server with an API

Tags: windows, automation, chat

In my project we are evaluating [Atlassian HipChat](https://www.hipchat.com/) server but it is very expensive once you pass the [10 users](https://www.hipchat.com/server#pricing). I need an alternative that meets as many as possible of following criteria:

- Deploy on our **own server** (otherwise we would use Slack)
- **Windows** Based (Although free/cheap **Linux** could be an option vs expensive Windows).
- It has an **API** so a ChatBot (like [Hubot](https://hubot.github.com/)) could be used
- It is open source / free or not very expensive.

Comment: Raw idea (not sure if that would fit your needs): Register an IRC channel (e.g. at Freenode), and use e.g. SupyBot or any other IRC compatible bot?

Comment: Could be... but one requirement is that should be hosted internally (Otherwise I would use Slack)

Comment: OK, so that would be OK provided there's an IRC server you could self-host (just in case someone comes up with one), right?

Comment: You should be able to host your own irc server if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [Mattermost](http://www.mattermost.org/). You can [download](http://www.mattermost.org/download/) it and install on your own server, e.g. via [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/). It has an [API](http://docs.mattermost.com/developer/api.html) and you can use compiled versions under MIT [license](https://github.com/mattermost/platform/blob/master/LICENSE.txt)

You also can look at [4 open source alternatives to Slack for team chat](https://opensource.com/business/15/9/alternatives-slack-team-chat).

Comment: Mattermost is for Linux but might be a good alternative. Thanks